# Excel Dynamic Print Is Skipping Data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have set up a dynamic print range in the name manager to ignore rows with formulas that don't return any values from another worksheet.  For the most part everything works, except it's skipping the last 8 rows of actual data.  Here's the OFFSET formula I'm using.

=OFFSET('Procurement Log'!$A$1,0,0,COUNT(IF('Procurement Log'!$B$8:$B$10003<>0,'Procurement Log'!$B$8:$B$10003)),24)

I can't figure out why I'd be losing those last 8 rows, unless it has to do with me starting the range on row 8?  I changed the range to start on B1 and it is now skipping the last 7 rows.  I'm lost.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

[Here's a link to the file][1].
The way it works is that new data is pasted into the Export Data tab, which is then pulled into the other two via formulas.  It's the blank cells with formulas that I'm trying to ignore on the dynamic print.

Comment: Please post online your spreadsheet (OneDrive, Dropbox etc).

Comment: @harrymc, I've added it to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added after link was provided:

Yes, the eight rows are the problem, as the first seven are not COUNT()-ed, and the eighth (B8 itself) has text so does not add to the count. But as mentioned you cannot fix it by changing the second range. You simply need to add 8 to the result of COUNT(). So like the formula shown at the end, below, except add 8 instead of adding 7. All your troubles will be gone.

(Side note:  the reason changing both ranges to B1 (vs. B8) changed the missing rows to 7 is the value in B6 is numeric and gets counted that way so the eight too few becomes only seven too few.)

Comment: GENIUS!  That worked perfect.  And your explanation makes perfect sense.  Thank you so much Jeorje!

Answer (score 0):

As `harrymc` is implying, definitely hitting the answer to this one really does need some more information and even a screenshot might be handy.

However, it appears you are testing a range (B8:B10003) and not a range from B1:wherever as that region has nothing of the dynamic material. In fact, its contents might even throw off the calculation. So far, so good.

However, the number of missing rows suggests that you do intend to print whatever is there in those untested rows as the dynamic range seems to start in A1, not A8 or what-have-you. The 8 missing vs. the 7 in B1:B7 isn't a spot on match, but in your other, related, question you make a statement that you are doing just what the other Answerer does, but it doesn't work out for you while other text in it suggests you only almost do what he does. So I'll assume perhaps the same inexactness applies here and bull ahead.

Seems like the dynamic data begins in row 8 and that column B is a convenient and accurate source for creating the right print range. And that you likely want to print some or all of the seven rows above that point as a start for the report, possibly also as a header (but probably not or with that many rows involved, you'd be missing a thousand or two.)

One assumes the data in that range is either numeric or undesired, so `COUNT()` is great and you do not need `COUNTA()`. The difference is the latter will count text cells as well. So the first potential problem:  perhaps, in the 10,000 rows, something like eight of those values actually are text. "HOW" only matters here to solving the source of that (as it is clearly not expected), and is not a precursor to even considering whether that could be it or not. So set two formulas up, one using each function over that range, and see if their results are the same. If not, then there are some red-headed text entries in the column. Those are not counted so the range ends up that many short of where it needs to end. Frankly, no matter how unlikely you consider that to be, it is absolutely the most likely source of trouble. Also, it could be part of the problem, and the rest something else. Do the test.

Moving on, testing the exact right range is certainly critical, so kudos for doing so. However, that is not necessarily exactly the range you want to generate the actual print area. Not on its own. So, say you do want to print starting at A1, so seven-ish rows of the calculated total will be used for rows 1-7, not for actual data. In other words, say the count is 2,433. As written, that would be range A1:X2433, but since it implies 2,433 rows in the rows 8 thru 10003, you would really want that many AND seven more. So if the calculation finds 2,433 items, you really need range A1:X2440, not A1:X2433. That would shave seven rows right off the report just from that.

How does this apply in your formula? You need to add those seven rows to the output of the `COUNT()` function. Right after its closing parentheses:

```
=OFFSET('Procurement Log'!$A$1,0,0,COUNT(IF('Procurement Log'!$B$8:$B$10003<>0,'Procurement Log'!$B$8:$B$10003))  +7,  24)
```

(just before the "24").

My bet is that gets you seven of the rows that are missing. And maybe a text entry exists somewhere in those 9,996 column B cells to get the other.

Changing the reference from B8 to B1 in the first use of it would add rows to the count if rows 1-7 have content (as the use in the test adds them into the count when just counting on them would not) and you say it is losing them, not gaining them, so that is not the issue. Changing it in the second use of it would probably (need to see the exact real spreadsheet page) lose them as the first seven are likely not numeric. Excel matches elements to elements, not addresses to addresses. That means that if the first seven elements of the range are non-numeric, their FALSE's will be matched up against the numeric entries of the test range (which starts at B8, presumably a numeric entry itself). So the first seven elements from the range of interest would be left out of the count making the dynamic print range seven rows short of being right.

Leaving the ranges matching, and adding a seven to the result of their parent function (`COUNT()`) accomplishes your goal without messing up the comparisons. Do that and I bet it begins to look very right. No messing with anything in the `COUNT()` function, just add the needed seven after it.

Lastly, I'll mention for anyone not having noticed that your situation presumably is one of formulas returning values in a continuous block down the rows until some point at which they do not, and never do again the rest of the way down. So you don't have data in rows 23, 24, 2438, 2499, and 2900. For those five as the only data, they'd be in rows 8-12. So you aren't using this to "hunt and peck" down the rows, so to speak, but rather taking as a block to print, the first row down until the first empty row and not caring about after that. This approach would not work in the least if they were spotted throughout.

It also means that some blank rows in between returned data are not the cause of the problem and that using a formula like one based upon `FILTER()` to pack them all into a continuous group will do nothing as they already are. (And if that is dead wrong and they ARE spotted about with blank lines in between, well, that is the source of your difficulty and it is time to bring `FILTER()` to bear on it!)

Comment: Thanks for all of the information Jeorje.  I've added the file to the original post above.